# What should I look for in a beginner guitar?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, beginner, equipment

I'm currently looking into buying an affordable and decent quality guitar, but I'm wondering what to look for? I noticed that there are 6-string guitars and 12-string guitars, which is best for a beginner?

I have been playing piano for four years and I want to play another instrument, I have learned up to a decent level of theory (level 7).

What should I look for when buying a guitar for beginners?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yamaha are a reputable company who make musical instruments of almost every sort,in all price ranges.   But it sponds as if you're a long way from knowing enough about guitars to make a sensible choice.  Take your first lesson before choosing an instrument.  Ask the teacher's advice.

Answer (score 4):

You definitely don’t want to start off with a 12 string, which requires a lot more finger strength and dexterity. My thoughts would be to just go to your local guitar shop and buy something cheap. That’s why I did anyway, 2 years later and I’m still playing on my crappy $120 steel string. You can also check out pawn shops. Gear doesn’t matter much as a beginner.

Comment: What you say seems to make sense, except that I do not agree at all that _gear does not matter to a beginner_: if poor equipment makes it hard to play or unpleasant to hear, you will regret your purchase and may be put off playing. A lot depends on how much you can spend and how much you expect to play.

Comment: @PJTraill - yep.  Another thing that must be considered is that many cheap guitars (like cheap violins, etc) are set up so poorly- especially in having action way too high- that they're very difficult to play at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yamaha do make some decent acoustics but I have found their *very* cheap ones aren't great, as they're mass produced in a factory which makes various other things, so as you can imagine they're not subject to the same quality control or craftsmanship as other companies are.

I've heard good things about [Freshman guitars](http://www.freshmanguitars.net/) - they're very well trusted, as are a lot of [Epiphones](https://www.dawsons.co.uk/epiphone-dr-100-dreadnought-acoustic-guitar?prod=102346&gclid=CjwKCAiArK_fBRABEiwA0gOOc8c464FOJRvm82DX4Shls57ecnOYimFfm-CaAc5sXbNdi6t31HXENxoCB4MQAvD_BwE) and [Tanglewood](http://www.tanglewoodguitars.co.uk/) guitars.

Some other things I'd want in a good acoustic - although this is arguably a matter of taste - is guitars with a satin finish on the neck. Some guitar necks have a lot of polycellulose lacquer on them which can make them sticky. You'll find it easier to play if you're not trying to work against friction from a highly polished neck.

As a user mentioned above, you definitely want to start with a 6 string, and not a 12, as they require some extra finger strength to press those extra strings and a slightly different playing style is required to play them successfully.

Answer (score -1):

The entry level and bottom of the line guitars are junk, unless you know what you are doing.  It's worth spending $250-400 on your first guitar to get something that sounds decent, has a relatively nice fretboard action, etc.

Seagull and Washburn are some possibilities.  For a little more money, Blueridge makes a nice entry level guitar.  I don't have any experience with Yamaha guitars.  But, I've played their keyboards, and they have a very nice action.  Yamaha makes a wide range of musical instruments, and is well-known in the music business.

It's a LOT easier learning on a nicer instrument.  The guitar will be easier to play, and it's less likely that you will get discouraged, and quit.

You definitely want to purchase a 6-string guitar.